# Facebook not recognizing my SSL certificate

Tags: angularjs, facebook, ssl, facebook-javascript-sdk, prerender

I have a site built in angularjs and working with prerender.io and with a SSL certificate from rapidssl and everything work fine...

Except from Facebook that is not showing the right information for the page.

When I open Facebook crawler

`Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid.`

And is not recognizing the values og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

It was working in the past, but it stop working I don't know why.

I googled and I concatenated my ssl.crt and my intermidiate.crt but without result.

My page is: https://www.granojo.com/video/10432

Comment: You have chain issues according to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.granojo.com

Comment: Hi! thanks for the information! I added the chain that the site generated me in the server and added to the ssl.conf file but after restarting the server I still get the same result... should I do anything else? should I wait some time? Should I add that to my hosting, in my Softlayer account (the hosting) I added also the certificate, the intermidiate cert, the private key and the CSR.. but there I cannot add the chain

Comment: My bad! I used the chain generated by this site (https://whatsmychaincert.com/) and it works great! thanks

Comment: https://whatsmychaincert.com/ saved the day!

Answer (score 3):

Your cert center isn’t providing an intermediate certificate as it should in the TLS handshake. Here is a solution how to chain your certification:

https://victorlava.com/how-to-fix-curl-60-ssl_cacert-cant-validate-ssl-certificate/